# tcsh alias arguments with no space around the arg selector

Tags: arguments, alias

I want to create an alias `alias gohost "ssh \!:1-machine"` so that I can do `gohost one` and it will do `ssh one-machine` or `gohost two` and it will do `ssh two-machine`.

But this alias says:
`Bad ! arg selector.`
Probably because there is no space around the selector in the alias. How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In case some lost soul comes here searching for answers, here it is:

`"ssh \!:1\-machine"`

i.e. escape the "-"